# Drop almost duplicates rows based on timestamp

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, drop-duplicates

I'm trying to remove some data almost duplicates. I'm looking for a way to detect the closest (`edited_at`) trip made by the user without losing informations.

So I want to solve this problem by calculating the difference between succesive timestamps and I remove minimum difference (zero in this example: step-1).

*I am open for other suggestions*

**Note:**

Don't use `drop_duplicates()` function.

**Dataframe:**

```
data = [[111, 121, "2019-10-22 05:00:00", 0],
        [111, 121, "2019-10-22 05:00:00", 1],
        [111, 123, "2019-10-22 07:10:00", 0], 
        [111, 123, "2019-10-22 07:10:00", 1], 
        [111, 123, "2019-10-22 07:10:00", 2],
        [111, 124, "2019-10-22 07:20:00", 0],
        [111, 124, "2019-10-22 07:20:00", 1],
        [111, 124, "2019-10-22 07:20:00", 2],
        [111, 124, "2019-10-22 07:20:00", 3],
        [111, 125, "2019-10-22 19:20:00", 0], 
        [111, 125, "2019-10-22 19:20:00", 1],
        [222, 223, "2019-11-24 06:00:00", 0], 
        [222, 223, "2019-11-24 06:00:00", 1], 
        [222, 244, "2019-11-24 06:15:00", 0],
        [222, 244, "2019-11-24 06:15:00", 1],
        [222, 255, "2019-11-24 18:15:10", 0],
        [222, 255, "2019-11-24 18:15:10", 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["user_id", "prompt_uuid", "edited_at", "prompt_num"]) 

df['edited_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['edited_at'])
```

**Step-1:**

```
111, 121, "2019-10-22 05:00:00", 0, somthing, 
111, 121, "2019-10-22 05:00:00", 1, somthing, 
111, 123, "2019-10-22 07:10:00", 0, 140,
111, 123, "2019-10-22 07:10:00", 1, 140,
111, 123, "2019-10-22 07:10:00", 2, 140,
111, 124, "2019-10-22 07:20:00", 0,  10,
111, 124, "2019-10-22 07:20:00", 1,  10,
111, 124, "2019-10-22 07:20:00", 2,  10,
111, 124, "2019-10-22 07:20:00", 3,  10,
111, 125, "2019-10-22 19:20:00", 0, 720, 
111, 125, "2019-10-22 19:20:00", 1, 720,
222, 223, "2019-11-24 06:00:00", 0,   0, 
222, 223, "2019-11-24 06:00:00", 1,   0, 
222, 244, "2019-11-24 06:15:00", 0,  15,
222, 244, "2019-11-24 06:15:00", 1,  15,
222, 255, "2019-11-24 18:15:10", 0, 720,
222, 255, "2019-11-24 18:15:10", 1, 720
```

**Step-2:**

```
111, 121, "2019-10-22 05:00:00", 0,  somthing,
111, 121, "2019-10-22 05:00:00", 1,  somthing, 
111, 124, "2019-10-22 07:20:00", 0,  10,
111, 124, "2019-10-22 07:20:00", 1,  10,
111, 124, "2019-10-22 07:20:00", 2,  10,
111, 124, "2019-10-22 07:20:00", 3,  10,
111, 125, "2019-10-22 19:20:00", 0, 720, 
111, 125, "2019-10-22 19:20:00", 1, 720,
222, 244, "2019-11-24 06:15:00", 0,  15,
222, 244, "2019-11-24 06:15:00", 1,  15,
222, 255, "2019-11-24 18:15:10", 0, 720,
222, 255, "2019-11-24 18:15:10", 1, 720
```

Comment: Neither Case 1 nor Case 2 was understood to be a clear standard. Isn't the latest date and the last data the same in chronological order? If that is the case. You can get it by `groupby().last()`.

Comment: I have updated my question to make it clearer with a track to explore

Comment: why is 7:10 zero if you have an early time of 05:00?

Comment: @Scott Boston sorry, it is an oversight, now is that clear to you ? The goal is to eliminate the `prompt_uuid` which are almost similar

Comment: Okay. now explain why are you eliminating the 7:10 what is the logic?  and in group 2 you are eliminating the first group at 6:00.

Comment: Imagine you are using a track application, you have gone through the points [0, 1, 2] and after realizing that it isn't true then you corrected your points by [0, 1, 2, 3] and the only one column that shows this difference `edited_at` most of the time are too close. This case explain `user_uuid: 111 & prompt_uuid: 123, 124`

Comment: @ALollz I must keep this `prompt_uuid`, the `prompt_uuid` that I want to delete often doesn't make much difference (sometimes it's milliseconds). I created this dataframe to make it clear but apparently it isn't the case. If you check my question this is just a suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your DataFrame is duplicated with respect to `['user_id', 'prompt_uuid']` taking a simple `diff` does not give the time difference between successive groups. First `drop_duplicates` then calculate the time difference within each `'user_id'`. You can then filter this to find the smallest time difference for each user:

```
s = df.drop_duplicates(['user_id', 'prompt_uuid']).copy()
s['time_diff'] = s.groupby('user_id')['edited_at'].diff(-1).abs()
s = s[s['time_diff'] == s.groupby('user_id')['time_diff'].transform('min')]

#    user_id  prompt_uuid           edited_at  prompt_num time_diff
#2       111          123 2019-10-22 07:10:00           0  00:10:00
#11      222          223 2019-11-24 06:00:00           0  00:15:00
```

Now if you want to further subset this to the rows where the time difference was within some small threshold (i.e. you're fine keeping a group where the minimum time difference is 4 hours...)

```
# Doesn't alter `s` in this example as both min_diffs are < 1 hour.
min_time = '1 hour'
s = s[s['time_diff'].le(min_time)]
```

Now `s` represents the unique `['user_id', 'prompt_uuid']` groups that you want to remove from the DataFrame. We accomplish this with an `outer` excluding merge, using the `indicator`:

```
keys = ['user_id', 'prompt_uuid']
df = (df.merge(s[keys], on=keys, how='outer', indicator=True)
        .query('_merge == "left_only"')
        .drop(columns='_merge'))
```

---

```
    user_id  prompt_uuid           edited_at  prompt_num
0       111          121 2019-10-22 05:00:00           0
1       111          121 2019-10-22 05:00:00           1
5       111          124 2019-10-22 07:20:00           0
6       111          124 2019-10-22 07:20:00           1
7       111          124 2019-10-22 07:20:00           2
8       111          124 2019-10-22 07:20:00           3
9       111          125 2019-10-22 19:20:00           0
10      111          125 2019-10-22 19:20:00           1
13      222          244 2019-11-24 06:15:00           0
14      222          244 2019-11-24 06:15:00           1
15      222          255 2019-11-24 18:15:10           0
16      222          255 2019-11-24 18:15:10           1
```

Comment: It doesn't cover all my real cases, but its give me an idea to solve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I may not understand all the requirements, but I've deduced from the example output I expect to see.' Split to get the status of the 'resp' column. Get the first row of that split status with `groupby().firts()`. Now we've fixed the column names and column order.

```
df1 = pd.concat([df, df['resp'].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1).drop('resp',axis=1)
df1 = df1.groupby(1, as_index=False).first().sort_values('edited_at', ascending=True)
df1.drop(0, axis=1,inplace=True)
df1.columns = ['resp','prompt_uuid','displayed_at','edited_at','latitude','longitude','prompt_num','uuid']
df1 = df1.iloc[:,[1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7]]

df1
prompt_uuid resp    displayed_at    edited_at   latitude    longitude   prompt_num  uuid
1   ab123-9600-3ee130b2c1ff foot    2019-10-22 22:39:57 2019-10-22 23:15:07 44.618787   -72.616841  0   4248-b313-ef2206755488
2   ab123-9600-3ee130b2c1ff metro   2019-10-22 22:50:35 2019-10-22 23:15:07 44.617968   -72.615851  1   4248-b313-ef2206755488
4   ab123-9600-3ee130b2c1ff work    2019-10-22 22:59:20 2019-10-22 23:15:07 44.616902   -72.614793  2   4248-b313-ef2206755488
3   zw999-1555-8ee140b2w1aa shopping    2019-11-23 08:01:35 2019-10-23 08:38:07 44.617968   -72.615851  1   4248-b313-ef2206755488
0   zw999-1555-8ee140b2w1bb bike    2019-11-23 07:39:57 2019-10-23 08:45:24 44.618787   -72.616841  0   4248-b313-ef2206755488
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that's not what i'm looking for. check I added more explanation, I apologize if I was not clear